# Error connecting to Hive using JayDeBeApi - Class not found

Tags: java, python, hive, jaydebeapi

I am trying to connect to my Hive server using JDBC connection.

I've the following JAR file in my JAVA_HOME:

- HIVEJDBC41.jar
- hadoop-common.jar

But when I run my code `jaydebeapi.connect('org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver', url)`

It gives me the following error:

```
raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver not found
```

**Note: My connection needs to be using JDBC connection.**

Anyone knows what I am missing?

Comment: Which version of Hive you are using ?

Comment: currently, it's the latest version 2.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mismatch of JDBC jar version

try  [hive-jdbc 2.3.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/2.3.7)

Comment: It still gives the same error :( The Jar must be on the JAVA_HOME directory, right? Or it must on same folder as Python script?

Comment: Add the jar into your classpath of project